# Jquery UI диалог

Tags: jquery

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>George</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="openD">Open Dialog</div
<div id="dialog"> test</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
$(«#dialog»).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
buttons: { «Да» },
«Нет»: function(){$(this).dialog(«close»);}}
});
$(«.openD»).click(function(){
$(«#dialog»).dialog(«open»);
});
});
                           });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Что тут не верно?

Answer (score 1):

1. Кавычки должны быть нормальными **"**
2. После "Да" уберите правую фигурную скобку **}**
3. Кнопке "Да", надо тоже что-нибудь присвоить.

В общем вот рабочий код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {"Да":"", "Нет": function(){
                                 $(this).dialog("close")
                         }}
    });
    $(".openD").click(function(){
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: не подскажите зачем заключить код в данную конструкцию?
<pre>
$(function(){
...
});
</pre>

Comment: Да, вы правы, один раз - лешнее. Исправил

Comment: @Demos а одинарные кавычки ненормальные чтоле? ^^

Comment: Одинарные - нормальные, а боковые - нет.

Comment: > не подскажите зачем заключать код в данную конструкцию?
$(function(){
...
});

Эта краткая запись эквивалентна `$(document).ready(handler)`, она описывает функцию, которая будет вызвана, когда полностью загрузится DOM. Подробнее о функции в [документации][1].


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: да, но там ситуация особая была, её уже исправили=)